# How does SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006 work exactly?

Tags: .htaccess

I ran into an issue ([When using fpm, it is not clear how to make image styles work](https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/issues/215)
) which I traced back to the use of Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006 in `sites/default/files/.htaccess`.

In order to continue debugging I would need a more solid understanding of what exactly "SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006" does in that file, because when I comment it out, my issue is resolved.

Is there code somewhere which "Handles" files? If so where? I have [searched Drupal and cannot find any actual logic behind this](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/search?q=Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/newsletters/security-advisories-for-drupal-core/2006-05-25/sa-2006-006-drupal-core-execution

Comment: From reading that, it appears that this is to prevent scripts in your files directory, where files are uploaded to, cannot be executed. Without this, a hacker could potentially upload a script to that directory and access it.

Comment: This is a question about Apache. (*What happens when the handler set for a directory doesn't exist?*) Drupal doesn't have any Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006.* file, as you already found out, which means that handler doesn't exist.